# Python urllib2 proxy ascii error

Tags: python, urllib2

My code just needs to connect to a webpage page through a proxy but allways receives the following error when reachs the "urllib2.urlopen" sentence:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3052, in run_code
    self.showtraceback()

 File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 1851, in showtraceback
    value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)

 File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1240, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)

 File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1157, in structured_traceback
    self, etype, value, elist, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context

 File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 511, in structured_traceback
    lines = ''.join(self._format_exception_only(etype, value))

 File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 623, in _format_exception_only
    Colors.Normal, s))

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 110: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Running Python 2.7 in Anaconda, Windows 7 64bit.

**My code:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socks
import urllib2

def urllib2_HTTP_test():
    socks.set_default_proxy(socks.HTTP, "<proxy_address>", <proxy_port>)
    socks.wrap_module(urllib2)
    status = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.python.org:80").getcode()
    assert status == 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
    urllib2_HTTP_test()
```

Comment: Please show full stacktrace, it may contain interisting elements.

Comment: Thank you Serge, my first post lack of experience

Comment: You have wrong implementation of socks library. See [https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks#sockssocksocket](https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks#sockssocksocket)

Comment: Even better, use `requests` package, where all methods are clear and easy to use. [http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/?highlight=proxy#proxies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/?highlight=proxy#proxies)

Comment: It seems that the proxy is not accepting my request and the program receives a message that cannot decode.

Comment: @JoseManuelSanchez you can try my pycurl example with the VERBOSE option  in True to see the connection log

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urllib2.ProxyHandler`, try this:

```
def urllib2_HTTP_test():
    proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '<proxy>:<port>'})
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    status = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.python.org:80").getcode()
    assert status == 200
```

or using `pycurl` as I prefer maybe something like:

```
import pycurl

def pycurl_HTTP_test(url, proxy, proxy_usr):
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(c.URL, url)
    c.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, proxy) #<-- ex. 'http://proxy:port'
    c.setopt(pycurl.PROXYUSERPWD, proxy_usr) #<-- ex. 'usr:pass'
    c.setopt(c.FAILONERROR, True)
    c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, False)
    c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
    try:
        c.perform()
    except pycurl.error, error:
        errno, errstr = error
        print 'An error occurred: ', errstr
    status = c.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE)
    assert status == 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
    url = "http://www.python.org:80"
    proxy = 'http://proxy:port'
    proxy_usr = 'usr:pass'
    pycurl_HTTP_test(url, proxy, proxy_usr)
```